# C# How to output 10 random strings from a list

Tags: c#, string

Hi there im new to programming and wanted to know how can i output 10 random strings from a list.
i have 10 strings however only one of them displays in random. i understand that i would need to loop it however i have no idea how to loop items in a list and make it display 10 times in random

```
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
            var list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four" ,"five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
            var random = new Random();
            int index = random.Next(list.Count);
            listBox1.Items.Add(list[index]);
```

Comment: Put your last two lines of code in a loop that repeats 10 times?

Comment: You can suffle the list and then display it, there are many algorithms that do that

Comment: @David there will then be duplicates

Comment: _i have no idea how to loop items_ [Iteration statements (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements)

Comment: @Cid: Does the OP want to randomly pull a string from a list 10 times, or show the entire list in randomly sorted order?  The question isn't clear about that.

Comment: @David that's true, to me it seemed clear that it was a shuffle problem, but after re-reading again, this point needs indeed clarifications

Comment: Also try `list.OrderBy((item) => rng.NextDouble());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to execute a piece of code multiple times. In this case you don't actually have to loop over the List itself since we don't care about the values itself.

```cs
listBox1.Items.Clear();
var list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
var random = new Random();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // We need to call random.Next() in the loop to get a different value each time.
    int index = random.Next(list.Count);
    listBox1.Items.Add(list[index]);
}
```

Comment: This will repeat some values. Maybe the _op_ does not intend for that to happen.